# comparing the edit control value with string

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

i have 2 edit control in dialog box. And onclick of Ok Button i want to compare this value with string.

```
case IDC_BUTTON1:
         UINT WINAPI GetDlgItemText(
  _In_   HWND hDlg,
  _In_   int nIDDlgItem,
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpString,
  _In_   int nMaxCount
);

 TCHAR szBuf[BUFF_LEN];
 TCHAR szBuf1[BUFF_LEN];
GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, szBuf, BUFF_LEN - 1);
GetDlgItemText(hDlg,IDC_EDIT2,szBuf1,BUFF_LEN-1);
```

now after that if condition check the value szBuf and szBuf1 but it say can not convert `cont char` to `tchar` how to convert this value.

Comment: What are you doing? Why are you have declaration in code? Please repost your question with valid code. Now downvote a flag question. Also for comparing string use lstrcmp(i).

Comment: Why are you using `TCHAR`. Use `wchar_t` or `wstring`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanx this is good idea.I want to check the value szBuf is equal or not to a string say ""hello. Is it possible to compare whole string once or need to use loop to check for every character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important details are leaking out in comments. That's too bad – the details should appear in the question. In particular you should at least have shown the line of code that performed the comparison and that led to the compiler error. And the compiler error should always be transcribed verbatim.

That said, it looks as though you are using either `wcscmp` or `_tcscmp` to perform the comparison. But you are passing `szBuf` which is a wide string for one argument, and a literal like `"hello"` for the other. The problem with that is that `szBuf` is a wide string and the literal is 8 bit, a `const char*`.

I hypothesise that you have written code this this:

```
int cmp = _tcscmp(szBuf, "Hello");
```

And the compiler objects because you have defined the UNICODE conditional and so `_tcscmp` expects both parameters to be of type `const wchar_t*`. The literal is not, it is `const char*`.

So the simple solution is to use a wide literal:

```
int cmp = _tcscmp(szBuf, _T("Hello"));
```

That said, I would not recommend using `TCHAR` in this day and age. I think it unlikely that you are still targeting Windows 98. Stick to the Windows native Unicode API and use wide strings. Declare your buffers like this:

```
wchar_t szBuf[BUFF_LEN];
```

And compare like this:

```
int cmp = wcscmp(szBuf, L"Hello");
```

Done that way it's much easier to understand what you are working with. Using `TCHAR` if you always compile with `UNICODE` defined is a pointless exercise that just results in obfuscated code.

Even better still though would be to avoid C strings as much as possible and use native C++ strings. For example `std::wstring` would be the obvious choice here. Clearly you need to use the C strings for the low-level Windows API calls, but as soon as they return you a value, transfer that to a C++ string and life will be so much simpler.

Comment: wcscmp(szBuf, L"Hello") give the right answer but if we store hello in wchar_t temp=L"hello" and now compare using wcscmp(szBuf,temp) it give answer 0 what is the problem

Comment: Well, the first string is **Hello** and the second string is **hello**. Notice the lack of a capital letter in the second.

Comment: it is not even working for Hello.

Comment: Did you mean `wchar_t temp=L"Hello"` or `const wchar_t* temp=L"hello"`?

Comment: okay.thanx actually it give 0 when both string are equal and 1 when not equal.

Comment: Well, that's what the documentation says ......